# Compare dataframe columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below:

df1:

```
ID   col1   col2    
1     A1     B1    
2     A2     B2     
3     A3     B3   
4     A4     B4   
5     A5     B5    
6     A6     B6
```

df2:

```
col1   col2   
 A1     B1     
 A2     O5   
 H3     B3     
 A4     B4    
 A5     66     
 A6     C6
```

Expected Result: I would like to generate a result df based on the condition -  Each value in col1,col2 of df1 should exist in col1,col2 values of df2

Expected Result df:

```
ID   col1   col2     Error
1     A1     B1      No mismatch with df2
2     A2     B2      col2 mismatch with df2
3     A3     B3      col1 mismatch with df2
4     A4     B4      No mismatch with df2
5     A5     B5      col2 mismatch with df2
6     A6     B6      col2 mismatch with df2
```

Comment: You do not have list in df2

Comment: list is a column in df1 and its value list1 and list2 are just dropdownlist names ; the accepted values are given in columns list1,list2 in df2. So, the data from column "value" of df1 based on its list value should be checked with df2 list1 & list2 values.

Comment: Edited the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create helper DataFrame with dictionary comprehension and comparing with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m = pd.DataFrame({c: ~df1[c].isin(df2[c]) for c in ['col1','col2']})
print (m)
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1  False   True
2   True  False
3  False  False
4  False   True
5  False   True
```

And then [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per rows and [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with matrix multiplication for get column names:

```
df1['Error'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), 
                        m.dot(m.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ') + ' mismatch with df2', 
                       'No mismatch with df2')
print (df1)
   ID col1 col2                   Error
0   1   A1   B1    No mismatch with df2
1   2   A2   B2  col2 mismatch with df2
2   3   A3   B3  col1 mismatch with df2
3   4   A4   B4    No mismatch with df2
4   5   A5   B5  col2 mismatch with df2
5   6   A6   B6  col2 mismatch with df2
```

Comment: m = pd.DataFrame({c: ~df1[c].isin(df2[c]) for c in ['col1','col2']}) - col1 and col2 are hard-coded. When I try to pass the column names directly from the dataframe using df.cols,    it says the below error "ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only" - Any help with this?

Comment: code should work if I pass all the columns from the dataframe like this                       lovcols = df2.columns                                                                                              m = pd.DataFrame({c: ~dfCSDataset[c].isin(dfLOVRules[c]) for c in [lovcols]}

Comment: @Osceria - yes, you are right. You can also pass columns to dict comprehension like  `m = pd.DataFrame({c: ~df1[c].isin(df2[c]) for c in df2.columns})`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick but there may be an easier way.

```
diff = pd.concat([df1[col] == df2[col] for col in df1], axis=1)

def m(row):
    mismatches = []
    for col in diff.columns:
        if not row[col]:
            mismatches.append(col)
    if mismatches == []:
        return 'No mismatch'
    return 'Mismatches: ' + ', '.join(mismatches)

df1['Error'] = diff.apply(m, axis=1)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Comment: Edited the Question

Comment: @Osceria do you get the same error with the following reproducible datasets: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"], 'col2': ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A1", "A2", "H3", "A4", "A5", "A6"], 'col2': ["B1", "O5", "B3", "B4", "66", "C6"]})`

Comment: It's because your `df1` and `df2` had different columns, right? I noticed you edited the question now, does it work with those dataframes?

Comment: If I run what I answered with the dataframes above, it seems like it works.

Comment: @lieblos -Yes, df1 has one extra column ID whereas df2 just has 2 cols